# Meaning of だって in this sentence

Tags: particles

It's a sentence from dragonball, the hearer (悟飯) just asked the speaker to create something to wear that could hide his identity without looking like a kind of body protection.

> どってことないじゃない！悟飯くんだってばれなきゃいいんでしょ？
>
> That's no big deal! It's gonna be ok as long as you don't get busted right?

I don't get the meaning of だって here, I know that most of the time it can be replaced by either も or でも but I don't see how either one would fit here.

Comment: 「どってこの」：typo of 「どってこと」?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「だって」 is not a constituent in your sentence.

「`悟飯くんだ`って」 is an abbreviation of 「`悟飯くんだ`ということ」 in casual speech.

**How the abbreviation takes place**

> At the very beginning: `悟飯くんだ`ということ
>
> 「と」 is replaced by 「って」: `悟飯くんだ`っていうこと
>
> 「いう」 is dropped: `悟飯くんだ`ってこと
>
> 「こと」 is dropped: `悟飯くんだ`って

**Similar instances**

> なんで`好きだ`ってばれたんですか。
>
> `女の子だ`ってばれちゃうじゃない？

Comment: I thought that if って had meant というのは or ということは it would have been directly attached to 悟飯 and didnt think about it as "The fact that you are Gohan". Thanks for your quick answer.